# HP Active Pen connection problem on HP EliteBook 830 G7

Tags: 20.04, hp, touchscreen

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on a HP EliteBook 830 G7. The HP Active Pen seem to be recognized since it is listed in the Bluetooth list in the settings. However, after a short time of connection after the pairing (paired-status is "Yes"), it disconnects. Is it possible to make the pen work?

Answer (score 0):

HP EliteBook 830 G7 does not work with an active pen. The touch screen is of capacitive type and works only with passive pens.